# Can't install AngularJS dependencies on Mac

Tags: node.js, angularjs, macos, git, npm

I would like to go through the AngularJS tutorial on my Macbook (64bit, Intel Core i7, OSX 10.9.4).

I've installed Git and Node, and I've cloned the repository, but I can't install the project dependencies using npm, for apparently the karma-chrome-launcher can't be found :

```
angular-phonecat user$ npm install
npm ERR! Error: Not found: karma-chrome-launcher@'^0.1.4'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["latest","0.0.1","0.0.2","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.1.4"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:313:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:274:15
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:67:7)
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/graceful-fs.js:31:9)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/transfer/Documents/GitHub/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.4.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.17
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/Documents/GitHub/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

I tried installing the package directly, but now I get a different error, telling me that the CPU type is wrong.  I get the same error message if I try run "npm install bower".  Could this be a 32bit / 64bit issue?  I've done some googling but I've not found anything useful.

```
angular-phonecat transfer$ npm install karma-chrome-launcher
npm ERR! tar "-mvxpf" "-" "-o" "-C" "/var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/contents/___package.npm" execvp(): Bad CPU type in executable
npm ERR! tar "-mvxpf" "-" "-o" "-C" "/var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/contents/___package.npm" 
npm ERR! Failed unpacking /var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/tmp.tgz
npm ERR! couldn't unpack /var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/tmp.tgz to /var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/contents
npm ERR! Error: Failed tar "-mvxpf" "-" "-o" "-C" "/var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/contents/___package.npm"
npm ERR! exited with 127
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:85:8)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:172:12)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
npm ERR!     at Array.0 (net.js:837:12)
npm ERR!     at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "karma-chrome-launcher"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/transfer/Documents/GitHub/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.4.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.17
npm ERR! gzip "--decompress" "--stdout" "/var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/tmp.tgz" execvp(): Bad CPU type in executable
npm ERR! gzip "--decompress" "--stdout" "/var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/tmp.tgz" 
npm ERR! Failed unpacking /var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/tmp.tgz
npm ERR! couldn't unpack /var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/tmp.tgz to /var/folders/qs/2kjpsc150f30c0p9v_0y7m100000gp/T/npm-1410421930167/1410421930167-0.4476239620707929/contents
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/transfer/Documents/GitHub/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Comment: maybe a problem with node version

Comment: how can this be a version problem with node?  I just installed the latest Macintosh installer.

Comment: It can be..it may be dependent on a specific node version...

Comment: ok, but what can I do about that?

Comment: it got installed on my machine with no hiccups i have Macbook (64bit, Intel Core i7, OSX 10.9.4) with node version 0.10.31

Comment: i just went in the folder and did sudo npm install and worked like a charm